# Can't seem to import scikit-learn's MLPRegressor

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, neural-network, importerror

So I'm trying to use scikit-learn's MLPRegressor, but python keeps spitting back an `ImportError: No module named MLPRegressor`. I'm currently trying to use the syntax `from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor`. I've uninstalled and reinstalled sklearn using Anaconda, and it still makes no difference.

I've tried to import it in several times, but I keep getting a different error, such as `NameError: name 'MLPRegressor' is not defined` by just including `import sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor` and then calling the constructor or `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MLPRegressor'` by calling the constructor with `sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor`.

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: It looks like it's only present in the development version of scikit-learn 0.18. http://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be the scikit version?  I can only find documentation for MLPRegressor in scitkit-learn 0.18.  The stable version is 0.17.

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html

Comment: Potentially. I can't seem to install the specific version, however. I tried `conda install scikit-learn=0.18.dev0` and `conda install scikit-learn=0.18`, but both times it said no packages found.

Comment: I think I may have found a suitable solution if this is the same MLPRegressor function you are looking for.  Would you mind if you starred this answer if it is right or very close?  I'm trying to build up reputation.  Thanks!
Documentation for Regressor:
http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module_mlp.html

Installation:
http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide_installation.html

Comment: I think the latter is the solution, but after installing g++ it's dumping thousands on thousands of lines with no error, so I'm not sure what's going on. However, my initial question was answered, so thanks!